# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrapform'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrapform'
```

When I run by `python manage.py runserver`, this error happens.
Traceback says

```html
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
        six.reraise(*_exception)
      File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
        module = import_module(entry)
      File "/Users/XXX/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrapform'
```

I wrote in settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'bootflat.github.io'), ]
```

Directory structure is like

```
-PythonServer
  -PythonServer
  -logic
   -static
    -index.css
   -templates
    -index.html
  -boolflat.github.io
  -bower_components
```

I run pip install django-versatileimagefield==1.2.2 & pip install rules, but same error happens.How should I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you installed bootstrap-form? If no, run the below command to install it.

```
pip install django-bootstrap-form
```

For more info : https://django-bootstrap-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/